# Implement 2d face filters with google ML Kit vision face detection Android Java

Tags: android, java-8, google-mlkit

There is an android sample app for ml vision kit https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

I want to implement face filters on face detection of that app.it returns Face object and it has face landmarks.

I got png image (sun glasses) and I want to draw it on canvas with getting face landmark positions. I did it but sun glasses not align with eyes and when I rotate the face, its not rotating.

implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.2'

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Face face = this.face;
    if (face == null) {
        return;
    }

    //getting left posion of eyes
    List<PointF> list=face.getContour(FaceContour.RIGHT_EYEBROW_TOP).getPoints();
    float left_x=translateX(list.get(0).x);
    float left_y=translateY(list.get(0).y);


    //getting right position of eyes
    list=face.getContour(FaceContour.LEFT_EYEBROW_TOP).getPoints();
    float right_x=translateX(list.get(0).x);
    float right_y=translateY(list.get(0).y);

    //create rectangle according to positions
    Rect rect=new Rect();
    Rect srcRect=new Rect();
    rect.set((int)(left_x),(int)left_y,(int)right_x, (int) right_y+150);

    //draw filter
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect , new Paint());


}
```

Comment: Did the returned face landmark have correct position when rotating face?

Comment: yes, they are correctly positioned

Comment: Then this sounds more like a UI drawing issue rather ML Kit SDK.